# Как использовать шаблон в AngularJS для динамически создаваемого элемента (контекстного меню)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, инспекция-кода

Нужно сделать контекстное меню в виде директивы AngularJS. Я пока что сделал так:

```
<span class="myelem" dd-ctx-menu="menuobj">Тестовый элемент</span>
```

Где menuobj - это объект со списком нужных полей в контекстном меню, ну а ddCtxMenu - это директива. В самой директиве я пока что все делаю "вручную", то есть создаю элемент `var menu = angular.element('<div class="ctxmenu"></div>');`, потом в цикле его наполняю, ставлю обработчики и отображаю на экран. Все работает, но мне сказали есть более правильный способ.

Интересует, как можно воспользовавшись шаблоном директивы, сделать так, чтобы заранее написать конструкцию контекстного меню и фреймворк бы сделал за меня работу по его наполнению.

Например шаблон такой для начала:

```
<div class="ctxmenu">
   <span  ng-repeat="elem in menulist">{{elem}}</span>
</div>
```

Как я прочел в документации и убедился на практике, если указать директиве шаблон через `templateUrl: 'template.html'`, то он перепишет элемент в соответствии с шаблоном, а мне надо чтобы этот шаблон только по клику активировался для построения меню. Я плохо еще знаю фрейморк и нечетко выражаю мысли, но надеюсь вы меня поняли.

Код директивы:

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('ctxMenuModule', [])
    .directive('ddCtxMenu', ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            // получаем объект с настройками меню
            scope: {
                menuobj: '=ddCtxMenu'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                // объект состояния элемента, используется обрабочиками и для isEnabled()
                var state = {};

                //создаем меню и навешиваем внутрь обработчики
                function createCtxMenu(menuobj) {
                    var menu = angular.element('<div class="ctxmenu"></div>');
                    for (let prop in menuobj) {
                        let itemobj = menuobj[prop];
                        let item = angular.element('<div>' + itemobj.name + '</div>');

                        if (itemobj.isEnabled(state)) {
                            item.addClass('ctxmenuitem');
                            item.on('click', function() {
                                console.log('44');
                                itemobj.handler(element, state);
                            })
                            //если есть подменю
                            if (itemobj.submenu) {
                                var submenu = createCtxMenu(itemobj.submenu);
                                menu.submenu = submenu;
                                item.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    var rect = item[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                                    $document.find('body').append(submenu);
                                    //смещаем меню.
                                    submenu.css({
                                        top: rect.top + 'px',
                                        left: rect.right + 'px'
                                    });
                                });
                                item.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                                    var rt = e.relatedTarget ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement;
                                    if (submenu[0] != rt && submenu[0] != rt.parentNode) {
                                        submenu.removeAll();
                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        } 
                        else {
                            item.addClass('ctxmenudisabled');
                        }
                        menu.append(item);
                    }
                    //удаляем меню и все подменю рекурсивно
                    menu.removeAll = function() {
                        menu.submenu ? menu.submenu.removeAll() : 0;
                        menu.remove();
                    }
                    menu.on('mouseover', function() {
                        menu.submenu ? menu.submenu.removeAll() : 0;
                    });
                    return menu;
                }

                //отслеживаем правый клик на элементе
                element.on('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    // удаляем текущее меню
                    var tmp = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.ctxmenu'));
                    tmp.length ? tmp.remove() : 0;
                    //создаем новое
                    var ctxMenu = createCtxMenu(scope.menuobj);
                    $document.find('body').append(ctxMenu);
                    //ставим обработчики кликов
                    var removeMenu = function() {
                        ctxMenu.removeAll();
                        $document.off('click', removeMenu);
                        $document.off('contextmenu', removeMenu);
                    }
                    $document.on('click', removeMenu);
                    $document.on('contextmenu', removeMenu);
                    //смещаем меню.
                    ctxMenu.css({
                        top: event.pageY + 'px',
                        left: event.pageX + 'px'
                    });
                });


            }
        };
    }
    ]);
})(window.angular);
```

Сам menuobj - это массив объектов вида:

```
$scope.menuobj = [
    {
        name: 'Удалить',
        handler: function(element, state) {
            element.remove();
        },
        isEnabled: function(state) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    ...];
```

Comment: добавь пример своей директивы, чтобы было видно что она делает

Comment: @Grundy сделал.

Comment: есть как минимум два варианта: попробовать использовать transclude, или использовать $compile сервис